# How to redirect subdomain to path AWS EC2 apache server & cloudflare

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain, cloudflare

I have two websites https://myweb.com (MERN stack website) & https://blog.myweb.com (WordPress website using apache server).
I Don't want a subdomain I want to route my blog website like this -> https://myweb.com/blog. both websites are hosted on ec2 & domain/subdomains are managed by Cloudflare.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case usually the [Resolve Override](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206190798-Using-Resolve-Override-in-Page-Rules) feature can be used so that:

- the DNS record for `myweb.com` points to origin server 1
- a Page Rule is created for path `myweb.com/blog`to **Resolve Override** to origin server 2

Please note that this feature is available on the Enterprise Plan, as documented